# Insert a String into the GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm still learning WPF and have searched for a way to do this that is not beyond my level of learning, but have not found an answer.  Hopefully someone can help me out!

The purpose of my application was to be a simple check-in/check-out program.  In my main application I list employees by name along with 2 buttons (in and out) as well as a comment field.

So far I've managed to open a new window when the 'In' or 'Out' buttons are clicked and prompt the user for a comment.  I've managed to pass that comment back to my MainWindow, but now I am at a loss as to how to display that in the GridView.

Here is what the MainWindow.cs looks like:

```
private void menuIn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;
    int rowNumber = lvUsers.Items.IndexOf(item) + 1;
    // MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Button row is {0}", rowNumber));

    string userCommentString = "";
    SubWindow subWindow = new SubWindow(userCommentString, rowNumber);
    subWindow.Show();
}
```

So the 'rowNumber' is the row that contains the comment field I want to change.  The 'userCommentString' is what I want to go into that row.  Is there not a simple way to insert a string into the grid if I know the row and column number?

Comment: Hi Josh!  I would recommend that you use MVVM.  Any answer that makes a small modification to your code will not be helpful to your WPF career because you are using traditional imperative programming techniques here.  If you were using MVVM the answer would be to simply insert your new item into the ObservableCollection that is databound to the control it is displayed in.

Comment: I have no plans to start a WPF career, I was only tasked with creating this checkout program because our old one is no longer functional and I took some programming classes in college.  The thought at the time was that this would be an "easy project" to do when I wasn't busy.  I am however willing to learn MVVM if you can point me to a good tutorial.

Comment: Properly following MVVM takes a fair amount of discipline, and is going to require a large investment in learning.  If you don't think that's the direction you want your career to go, you may want to consider WinForms over WPF.  The "code behind pattern" is far easier and more forgiving with WinForms than WPF.

Comment: "I've managed to pass that comment back to my MainWindow"  We don't see any code in your question that indicates this is actually happening, but that's where the problem probably is. Please post a bit more of your solution. (I'd also promote MVVM, but everyone else has already done so.)

Comment: This is my subwindow.cs where I capture the comment and pass it back to Mainwindow:

private void textboxButton_Click(object obs, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    strUserComment = userCommentBox.Text;
    //MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Your comment was: {0}", 
    strUserComment));
    this.Close();
    MainWindow subWindow = new MainWindow(strUserComment, userNumber);
}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example how you could do that. Beside this, I would also recommend to learn MVVM.

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvUsers">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Comment" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Comment}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Button">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="6,2,6,2">
                            <Button Content="Click" Click="Button_Click" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Add items to ListView

```
lvUsers.Items.Add(new Test() { Name = "User A" });
lvUsers.Items.Add(new Test() { Name = "User B" });
lvUsers.Items.Add(new Test() { Name = "User C" });
```

Manipulate row on button click:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Get row number
    var item = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;
    int rowNumber = lvUsers.Items.IndexOf(item);

    //Use row number to manipulated the right row
    //This should be done after comment is passed back to MainWindow
    Test t = (Test)lvUsers.Items[rowNumber];
    t.Comment = "new comment";
    lvUsers.Items.Refresh();
}
```

Test class:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a error on this line:

Test t = (Test)lvUsers.Items[rowNumber];

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'    lvUsers was null.

What is this telling me?

Comment: Did you used the `Test` class to add items to lvUsers?

Comment: Edit: Too long for a comment, perhaps need a new question.

Comment: Didn't know how to answer this question without just showing my code.  I have put the whole mainwindow and subwindow cs code in this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722821/wpf-update-column-in-listview

Comment: I've added an answer to the other question :)