# WPF Update column in listview

Tags: c#, wpf

I am a novice who is trying to attempt a "simple" program and don't even know how to ask this correctly, but let me try this again.  Credit to user Ben for helping me get this far!

I am trying to have a simple check-in and check-out program that populates names from a list, with a button that allows user to change their status and leave a comment (ex: Back at 2pm - Meeting Downtown).

## Here is my MainWindow.CS:

```
namespace SimpleInOut
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<Test> items = new List<Test>();
        lvUsers.Items.Add(new Test() { Name = "User A" });
        lvUsers.Items.Add(new Test() { Name = "User B" });
        lvUsers.Items.Add(new Test() { Name = "User C" });
    }
    public MainWindow(string strUserComment)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<Test> items = new List<Test>();
        lvUsers.Items.Add(new Test() { Name = "User A" });
        lvUsers.Items.Add(new Test() { Name = "User B" });
        lvUsers.Items.Add(new Test() { Name = "User C" });

        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Your comment is: {0}", strUserComment));
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Your userNumber is: {0}", userNumber));

        //Message box checks above are correct
        //However, it is not changing the comment box to the strUserComment - why?!
        Test t = (Test)lvUsers.Items[userNumber];
        t.Comment = strUserComment;
        lvUsers.Items.Refresh();
    }

     public static string strUserComment { get; set; }
     public static int userNumber { get; set; }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Get row number
        var item = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;
        userNumber = lvUsers.Items.IndexOf(item);

        SubWindow subWindow = new SubWindow();
        subWindow.Show();
    }
}

    public class Test
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## Here is my Subwindow.cs:

```
namespace SimpleInOut
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for SubWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class SubWindow : Window
{
    public SubWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string strUserComment = userCommentBox.Text;
        //MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Your comment was: {0}", strUserComment));
        this.Close();
        MainWindow subWindow = new MainWindow(strUserComment);
    }
}
}
```

The critical question is in Mainwindow.CS where I check to see that the user number and comment were passed from the Subwindow correctly - and they were.  However, I can't seem to get the comment (strUserComment) to display in the list.

## In case this is needed, here is the MainWindow XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvUsers">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Comment" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Comment}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Button">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="6,2,6,2">
                                <Button Content="Click" Click="Button_Click" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

## And this is the subwindow XAML:

```
<Grid Margin="8">
    <TextBox Name="userCommentBox" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="25" MaxLength="50" />
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Width="40" Click="Button_Click">OK</Button>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example how it could work. I'm using the `Closed` event of the SubWindow to get the information back to the MainWindow.

MainWindow.cs:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    List<Test> items = new List<Test>();
    lvUsers.Items.Add(new Test() { Name = "User A" });
    lvUsers.Items.Add(new Test() { Name = "User B" });
    lvUsers.Items.Add(new Test() { Name = "User C" });
}

private int clickedRowIndex = -1;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;
    clickedRowIndex = lvUsers.Items.IndexOf(item);
    SubWindow subWindow = new SubWindow();
    subWindow.Closed += SubWindow_Closed;
    subWindow.Show();
}

private void SubWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SubWindow sw = (SubWindow)sender;
    Test t = (Test)lvUsers.Items[clickedRowIndex];
    t.Comment = sw.UserComment;
    lvUsers.Items.Refresh();
}
```

SubWindow.cs:

```
public SubWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UserComment = userCommentBox.Text;            
    Close();
}

public string UserComment { get; set; }
```

Comment: This 100% does what I need it to do!  I had no idea you could send it through the closed event of the secondary window.  Thanks!